# MYSQL Performance on subquery count of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, cakephp

Hi I'm looking at some very old code on a CakePHP 2.x site.

There are two tables order and order_products. The orders table contains 2500+ records and the order_products table contains 38000+ records.

The following query is taking around 16 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT `Order`.`id` as id, 
(SELECT SUM(sub_total) AS total FROM order_products WHERE (order_id = `Order`.`id`) GROUP by order_id) AS `Order__order_total` 
FROM `orders` AS `Order`;
```

I understand that this query should be changed to contain the total on order table, however my question is that is this performance normal on such small record sets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
SELECT o.id, 
       (SELECT SUM(op.sub_total) AS total
        FROM order_products op
        WHERE op.order_id = o.id
       ) G AS `Order__order_total` 
FROM `orders` o;
```

Then you want an index on `order_products(order_id, sub_total)`.  The performance should significantly improve.

Comment: Wow i didn't realise there weren't indexes... Thank you Gordon.